# ListView Windows 8, Can we change Swipe left/Right behavior to Swipe Up/Down

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8, swipe-gesture

In my windows 8 application I have multiple ListViews inside a GridView with HorizontalScrollMode enabled. What I want is to override Swipe left/right gestures of ListViews.

I want to replace Swipe Left/Rigt (Select/UnSelect) to Swipe Down/Up (Select/Unselect),
I tried playing with ItemContainerStyle and only relevant thing I found is

```
<VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
```

and

```
 <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

But it doesn't seems to solve my problem as I want to change the behaviour.
How can I do that is it possible ? if not any work around?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly, but I think the easiest way might be to replace a `ListView` with a `GridView`.